# Deleting a linked-list node at a given position

Tags: python, linked-list

I have solved this particular problem using Recursion but I am not able to solve this question using ***While loop***. Here's my code, error, and the link to the question:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/delete-a-node-from-a-linked-list

**Code**

```
def Delete(head, position):
    list=head
    while(position-1):
        head=head.next
        position=position-1
    add=head.next
    head.next=add.next
    return list
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "solution.py", line 76, in <module>
head = Delete(L1.head, p)
File "solution.py", line 60, in Delete
head=head.next
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Comment: You should post a minimal version of your code capable of reproducing the error, not just the `Delete` function. Also, you're missing some indentation.

Comment: Where are you decrementing position?

Comment: `list` is a bad variable name because it shadows the built-in list constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're not handling the base condition where position is 0
2. You're not decrementing `position` in the loop
3. You don't need an extra variable when implementing the deletion logic
4. (*Statutory Warning*) `List/list` are all bad/not-meaningful names, do avoid using them.

---

```
def Delete(head, position):
    temp = head
    if position == 0:
        return temp.next

    while position - 1 > 0:
        head = head.next
        position -= 1
    head.next = head.next.next
    return temp
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
def delete(head, position):
    if position:
        # step ahead to node preceding the target
        here = head
        for _ in range(position - 1):
            here = here.next
        # snip the target out of the list
        here.next = here.next.next
        return head
    else:
        # special case - remove head node
        return head.next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def Delete(head, position):
    current = head
    previous = None
    found = False
    count = 0

    while not found:
        if count == position:
            found = True
        else:
            previous = current
            current = current.next
        count += 1

    # previous hasn't changed, node we're looking for is the head
    if previous == None:
        head = current.next
    else: # we're somewhere between head and tail
        previous.next = current.next

    return head
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive implementatioin

```
def deleteNode(node, position):
   if position == 0:
      return node.next
    
   if not node:
      return None

   if position <= 1:
      node.next = node.next.next
      return node

   node.next = deleteNode(node.next, position - 1)

   return node
```