# Deleting a node from the position indicated by the index

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I am having a issue, where my program is not deleting a node, which is passed in.

The delete function is following:

```
def delete(self, index):
        if index == 0:
            self.head = self.head.next
        else:
            current = self.head
            for i in range(index-1):
                current = current.next
            current.next = current.next
        self.size -= 1
```

The passing of the data is made by following;

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    L = LinkedList()
    #append
    L.append(4)
    L.append(1)
    L.append(2)
    L.print()

    #delete
    L.delete(1)
    L.print()
```

Excpected output:

```
4 -> 1 -> 2
4 -> 2
```

Actual output:

```
4 -> 1 -> 2
4 -> 1 -> 2
```

I know this might be partially the same as [Deleting a linked-list node at a given position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020095/deleting-a-linked-list-node-at-a-given-position) but I can't really get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement:

```
current.next = current.next
```

is not changing `current.next`.

Should be:

```
current.next = current.next.next
```

You'll also want to avoid running out of your list when `i` is out of range:

```
    def delete(self, index):
        if not self.head or i < 0:
            return  # out of range
        if index == 0:
            self.head = self.head.next
        else:
            current = self.head
            for i in range(index-1):
                current = current.next
                if not current:
                    return  # out of range
            if not current.next:
                return  # out of range

            current.next = current.next.next
        self.size -= 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond, yep, I understand now the next.next. `if not self.head or i < 0:` gave an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment` , but I worked out that `if not index in range(self.size):`  does the trick too. Thanks

Comment: That's completely on me, sorry and thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I m not going to give complete answer ,but point out some issues with your code.

1. if `index == 0`  and your list is empty, it will throw exception when you call delete. You need to change it to `if index == 0 and self.head:`
2. In the for loop, if `index == 1` what do you think will happen with `for i in range(0)` ? It will never go into the loop.
3. `current.next = current.next` is not going to have any effect. Instead I believe you should have `self.head.next = current.next` after checking `current` is not NULL.

Comment: Yep, I can see my erros now (also because of the other solution), but I get your points, and I understant that my loop had no sense. Thanks for the answer, this gave me vision on what to work on when debugging my code.

Comment: Point 3: it is not always correct to do `self.head.next =` (imagine `index=5`). Point 2: there is no problem here when the other points are correctly dealt with.

Comment: @trincot its not a complete answer. its only a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Then I believe you should take out point 2, as it is not a general problem (you call it an "issue"). It would nudge the asker in the wrong direction. They don't need to change that. Also the statement `self.head.next =` should not occur in their code, so suggesting it, is again nudging in the wrong direction, in my opinion.